# Should we accept the PSR on the grounds of cognitive faculty?

Tags: theology, atheism

Feser said in his publication, "Scholastic Metaphysics - A Contemporary Introduction" that if we reject the PSR, we're undermining any possibility of rational inquiry. Also in Pruss' paper, "PSR and Probability", he says that a localized version of the PSR or rejection of the PSR entails that we can't rationally estimate the probability of any event.

I'll concede that at best it rejects knowledge of cause and effect, which is the basis for scientific reasoning. However I don't see how just because the PSR is false, our thoughts are true or false.

One could also invoke Schopenhauer's fourfold roots of the PSR, without it entailing theism at all.

Comment: Seeing how the standard interpretation of quantum mechanics rejects PSR, the grim predictions for rational inquiry and probability seem to be greatly exaggerated. Of course, letting go of PSR should not excuse giving up search for causes too soon, but that makes it a useful psychological and methodological heuristic, not a metaphysical principle. For history and modern perspectives on PSR see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sufficient-reason/).

Comment: It's more that the PSR doesn't hold at a quantum level. If you check out Pruss' paper, he uses Bayes Theorem to conclude why it would be impossible for us to calculate the probability of any event (which is the case at quantum level). So I don't reckon this critique functions.

Comment: This is not a critique, more of a suggestion: you should take grandiose claims by authors with an agenda (theistic, in the case of Feser and Pruss) with a grain of salt. If you want a critique of Pruss's arguments specifically it is not hard to find, see e.g. [Kleinschmidt](https://philpapers.org/rec/KLERWT) (she is a theist, btw), or you can ask a separate question about them. But people were doing probability without PSR, or even metaphysics, before and after QM, whether it was "rational" by Pruss's standards or not. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. While I do agree that they have a theistic bias, they are philosophers of religion and using the PSR as an argument for God. I have also seen Van Inwagen's argument of the PSR, and the creation of the W-PSR which Pruss desperately holds onto. Though I'll check her out thanks, and the PSR does predate quite back, the concept of it anyways. Leibniz was the one who just gave the concept a name. So we've been using the PSR for the basis of scientific reasoning for ages.

Comment: No, cognitive faculty may give rise to PSR, e.g. our brains are wired to look for reasons...

Comment: Are you coming at this from Hume's perspective on casuality by any chance? I can feel some relation.

Comment: @Conifold there is no reason to give up the PSR based on the observations we have made related to quantum mechanics. In fact, in all the double-slit experiment variants, we still suppose that there is a cause to the observed effect, we simply have yet to uncover it. Stating that we don't know the sufficient reason for the effect, therefore there is no reason, or cause, for the effect, is just laziness.

Comment: @jaredad7 "We" do not suppose it anymore. Standard interpretations of quantum mechanics interpret collapse as purely random with no determining cause, and most physicists are not looking to uncover such a cause. Looking for something that does not exist (as they believe) is just wasteful. The truth is that "we" never had a good reason to believe PSR in the first place. It is a good methodological maxim to not give up too soon when looking for explanations, but it does have its limits. And transforming it into a metaphysical principle was a major leap of faith and wishful thinking

Comment: @Conifold the point is that their conclusion that the collapse is somehow uncaused (and therefore no cause exists) is wrongheaded. Random and uncaused are not the same thing.

Comment: @jaredad7 It is not uncaused, it is not determined (sufficiently caused). Prior events determine a set of possible outcomes and their probabilities, but sampling of the actual outcome from this set they do not, that part is random. Physicists did not arrive at this lightly, and many not even willingly, it is the surmise of a long research and attempts at "completing" the theory, including by some of the brightest minds. At this point, it is disputing it on the basis of some armchair principle that is wrongheaded. Time to acknowledge that nature may not operate the way we wish it to.

Comment: @Conifold even undetermined events are not sufficient cause (pun intended) for rejecting the PSR. Like the Principle of Non-Contradiction, we accept the PSR axiomatically, or at least we classicists do. That's why Feser says that rejecting it undermines rational inquiry. I suspect that if I told you that quantum observations undermine the PNC (light is a particle and a wave at the same time; the spin on quarks exists in superposition prior to observation), you'd reject this interpreation and postulate it is more likely we are missing information. It is the same for the PSR.

Comment: I will need to review Feser's Scholastic Metaphysics first, but I will answer this question when I'm at home and have had time to reread the relevant section.

Comment: @jaredad7 The analogy is not great. PNC is a content-neutral logical convention that we use to organize our theories, without it (or, at least, paraconsistency) they would have no content because anything goes. PSR is nothing of the sort. It is a bold metaphysical generalization with empirical content. Accepting such claims "axiomatically" without thorough testing is highly unadvisable on general grounds, and accepting them *after* there are clear empirical indications to the contrary is what really undermines rational inquiry.

Comment: @Conifold if we reject the PSR, we have no reason to seek reasons for any effects whatsoever. It certainly undermines any inductive processes.

Comment: @jaredad7 Where did this come from? We have plenty of reasons to seek reasons for all effects without PSR. Just because they are not guaranteed to always be there does not mean that they are never there, or even most of the time. And we certainly want them when they are. This just substitutes motivation and methodology for metaphysics. If acknowledging uncertainty undermined inquiry we'd be hopelessly undermined by human nature from the start, and inventing wishful principles to screen out reality generally makes things worse, not better.